# Prove that two random variables are dependent

Tags: random-variables, uniform-distribution, independence

Given two random variables X and Y where X is uniformly distributed on [-1,1] and Y = X^2, prove that these two random variables are dependent. Of course, it's clear that they are dependent. But, how could I prove it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Establish that the probability for Y to be greater than 1/2 is different from the conditional probability for Y to be greater than 1/2, conditional on $X$ being between 0 and 1/2.